# EditText TextInputLayout Hint text alignment: Is there a way to align hint text like textAlignment property of EditText view

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout, hint

I have an inputText field(TextInputLayout's EditText) of fixed height.
I want to align hint text to top left of the view.

**Problem:** hint text is always displayed at center_verticle but I want to display it at top left corner.

```
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/aboutWrapper"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="About Sponsor">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_about_sponsor"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="250dp"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:gravity="start|top"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textColorHint="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_medium" /> 
         </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: I tried your code and the text is displayed at the top left corner

Comment: Use a TextInputLayout

Comment: try to put inside the editText this: android:hint="hello" and you will see the result

Comment: @KKKKK you are confusing text with hint... i need hint alignment

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti i've tried TextInputLayout  but can't work out the solution...
can you give some example of working solution..

Answer (score 7):

As per this [github issue](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/933) you need to set **android:minLines** to at least 2 along with **android:gravity="top"**.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
 android:id="@+id/txtInput"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:hint="Hint">

 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
     android:id="@+id/et_content"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:gravity="top"
     **android:minLines="2"**
      />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="About Sponsor">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:minHeight="250dp"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:gravity="start|top"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
                .../>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: idk why... but it is not behaving same for me... although I am using same attribs

Comment: @MuahmmadTayyib Are you using a `MaterialComponents` theme in your app? Also I am using a `TextInputEditText` instead of a `EditText`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"` style to the `TextInputLayout`

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/aboutWrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="About Sponsor">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_about_sponsor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="250dp"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="start|top"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textColorHint="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_medium" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Message"
            android:gravity="left|top"
            android:inputType="textAutoComplete"
            android:textAlignment="textStart" />
```

Here `gravity` attribute will help in aligning the text to whichever you want.
You can Refer [Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#attr_android:gravity)

Answer (score 0):

Try this android:gravity="center"

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Enter your email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```